# What is $[\frac{q}{p}]$ if $[\frac{-q}{p}]=1$?

Tags: number-theory

What is $[\frac{q}{p}]$ if $[\frac{-q}{p}]=1$? There $[\frac{q}{p}]$ is Legendre symbol. In other words if $x^2 \equiv -q \pmod p$ is solvable, then is $x^2 \equiv q \pmod p$ solvable also? I get that it can be both solvable and not solvable, because

$[\frac{-1}{p}][\frac{q}{p}]=[\frac{-q}{p}]=1 $ $ \Leftrightarrow$ $[\frac{-1}{p}]=1=[\frac{q}{p}]$ or $[\frac{-1}{p}]=-1=[\frac{q}{p}]$.

Comment: Note that $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ is solvable but $x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod 3$ is not.  But in mod 5 it works.  Most books that cover Legendre symbols will discuss this.

Comment: $[\frac{-1}p]$ depends on $p\pmod 4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the squares in $(\Bbb Z/\Bbb Zp)^\times$ make up the only index 2 subgroup, one has that
$$
\text{square}\cdot\text{square}=\text{non-square}\cdot\text{non-square}=\text{square}
$$
and
$$
\text{square}\cdot\text{non-square}=\text{non-square}.
$$
Thus
$$
\text{$q$ and $-q$ are both squares or non-squares}\iff\text{$-1$ is a square}.
$$
Finally, it's a straightforward exercise to show that $-1$ is a square if and only if $p\equiv1\bmod4$.

Comment: How does square$\cdot$ square=nonsquare$\cdot$ nonsquare = square can be formulated by using $[\frac{q}{p}]$? Does square mean that $x^2 \equiv q \pmod p$ is solvable? So then$[\frac{q}{p}]=1$? Why you need to show that $[\frac{-1}{p}]=1$ iff $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$? thanks.

Comment: By the way does anyone know what is the command for calculating Legendre symbol or even Jacobi symbol in wolframalpha?

Comment: @Alvoutila: yes, a square is an element of the form $x^2$, whatever field you are in. By definition $\binom qp=1$ iff $q$ is a square $\bmod p$. Thus $\binom{ab}p=\binom ap\binom bp$. To compute Legendre/Jacobi symbols, it is by far more fun to do it by hand with the aid of Gauss' reciprocity law.

Comment: But now if $[q/p]=[-q/p] = 1$ and $[-1/p]=-1$ then it is contradiction. Am I right?

Comment: @alvoultai: But that is the never the case. The Legendre symbol is multiplicative in the numerator.

Comment: @ Andrea: What you aim at saying that "Legendre symbol is multiplicative in the numerator"?

Comment: @alvoultai: the answer to your last question is embedded in my first comment (Hint: "Thus ..."). Read it!